# remote postgresql 9.3 login using pgadmin3 and a public network server to connect to LAN-only machine

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, connectivity

I want to connect to a machine running postgresql 9.3. The machine itself is not reachable via a direct IP but is in a LAN with another machine with a public IP address.

My current approach is:

changing postgresql.conf:

```
/..../ 
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
/..../
```

adding to pg_hba.conf:

```
/..../
host    all        all        192.168.59.1/24       trust
/..../
```

(of cause restarting the postgres service)

connecting to the public server via:

```
ssh -L 9999:192.168.59.130:5432 user@theip
```

which works just fine (I am logged in without any error message)

But when I try to connect pgadmin3 using:

```
name: randomName
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 9999
Service:
Maintenance DB: postgres
Username: postgres
Pasword: *********
Colour:
Group: Servers
```

I get:
Server doesn't listen ....

checking `sudo netstat -tulpn` shows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8860/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      8860/postgres
```

Therefore postgres seems to listen for LAN addresses though I get a "do not listen".

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
host    all        all        192.168.59.1/24       trust
```

to

```
host    all        all        samenet       trust
```

did the trick for me. Though the difference between the two stays a secret for me.